# How are multiple my.cnf's loaded by MySQL?

Tags: mysql, my.cnf, client

If I want to replicate how the MySQL/Maria client reads `~/.my.cnf`, `/etc/my.cnf`, etc, how would I do it?

The [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) give a list of paths and mention "top files are read first, files read later take precedence", is that on a key-value basis or the *entire* file?

Answer (score 1):

The standard config file format applies. It is on group and key basis.

So if you have:

```
[mysql]
some_variable = 1

[client]
some_variable = 3
```

and after another file has

```
[mysql]
some_variable = 2
```

Then `some_variable` under mysql will be 2 but under client it will stay 3.

> The only relevant part for MySQL server is the [mysqld] though.

The easiest way to determine which files are being read is to strace the mysql process on startup.

1. Start MySQL with the normal init script and run `ps -ef|grep mysqld`.
2. Copy `/usr/sbin/mysqld`
3. Then run strace on the command grepping `.cnf`.

You should see something like this:

```
$ strace /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/databases/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log --pid-file=/databases/mysql/data/server.local.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306 2>&1 |grep .cnf
stat("/etc/my.cnf", 0x7fffa6edeb40)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5454, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", O_RDONLY)     = 3
stat("/usr/etc/my.cnf", 0x7fffa6edeb40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/root/.my.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=73, ...}) = 0
open("/root/.my.cnf", O_RDONLY)         = 3
stat("/root/.mylogin.cnf", 0x7fffa6edeb40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("./auto.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0660, st_size=56, ...}) = 0
open("./auto.cnf", O_RDONLY)            = 13
stat("/root/.mylogin.cnf", 0x7fffa6edeb40) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: The _server_ will read those files, but won't read any of those variables -- it looks only at `[mysqld]`.

Comment: Yes, of course. I should have mentioned that this is only for example. I'll edit the answer to clarify. Thanks!